# How to build CEF1 for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, chromium-embedded

I need to use CEF1 (not CEF3) and I need to do it in VS2017 (rest of the project is in VS2017). Which is a bit of problem, as VS2017 didn't exist at the time of CEF1. I don't even know how to begin. I tried to compile CEF1 in older Visual Studio, but then got linker error for mismatching _MSC_VER

Comment: Do you mean the binary distribution of CEF1 or building CEF1 + Chromium from source?  Which build? What is the linker error number?  (I don't have answers, just making the question clear.)

Answer (score 2):

Before I start my answer I need to say that it is highly recommended that you use CEF3 instead. The reasons include:

- CEF3 is in active development, currently receiving support, improvements and bug fixes.
- CEF3 uses modern versions of Chromium under the hood. E.g. 61 and 62 and the time of writing.
- CEF1 is stuck at Chromium 27.
- CEF3 can be started in a [single process](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/_cef_settings_t.html#single_process) mode, similar to how CEF1 was functioning. This is the biggest reason in my opinion one might want to use it. (Actually I wonder why do you want to use CEF1?)

My answer:

1. **If you can find the branch number you want in this [archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromiumembedded/downloads) (it has binaries for some older CEF1 branches)** or if you already have some binaries then you should be able to link them against your VS 2017 project no problem.
2. If not, then you need to build CEF1 from source. The easiest way in my mind is to satisfy the system [requirements](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding#markdown-header-legacy-release-branches-unsupported) for building the release branch 1453 (the last one to support CEF1):

   - Having VS2010
   - Windows 8 SDK
3. You could also try to build CEF1 in VS2017. In this way you are likely to encounter more build errors.

Once the 2nd or 3rd step is complete you can use the output in the VS2017 C++ project.

Comment: Are you saying it is possible to build and run project just with header files and *.lib files, without the *.dll files?

Comment: I think it should be possible to build the project with libcef_dll_wrapper.lib and some source code (headers and such). To be able to run it you'll need libcef.dll and some other assets (auxiliary DLLs, *.pak and locales).

Comment: For anyone else reading this  - the cef forums and wiki page strongly discourage using single process mode in production, so that could actually be taken as an advantage of cef1.